# Transfer from Multisite WordPress setup to Single WordPress setup

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have situation in which I want to transfer One site from my WordPress mutisite setup to Single WordPress setup.

I have transfer **"theme"**,**"uploads"** folder and **"related site database"**

from database I have removed multisite tables such as :

1) wp_site
2) wp_sitemeta
3) wp_blogs
4) wp_blog_versions
5) wp_signups
6) wp_registration_log

But when I tried to open **"wp-admin"** , It shows you do not have sufficient permission to access.

What I am missing here ??

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [All-in-one WP Migration plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) with the [Multisite extension](https://servmask.com/products/multisite-extension) it will drastically save you time, headaches and chasing errors.